# Rust optional iterator default value

Tags: rust

I have a custom optional iterator of optional values. If that value is `None` I would like to provide a default iterator of `None` values. However, I cannot get the types to match. Below is a [reduced example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=14e1ff81b08491605beba0e04f367469). Any suggestions of how to handle this?

```rust
use std::iter;

fn main() {
    let i = Some(vec![Some(1), Some(2), Some(3)]);
    let x = i.unwrap_or(iter::repeat(None).take(3));
    for y in x {
        println!("{:?}", y);
    }
}
```

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:5:25
  |
5 |     let x = i.unwrap_or(iter::repeat(None).take(3));
  |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Vec`, found struct `std::iter::Take`
  |
  = note: expected struct `Vec<Option<{integer}>>`
             found struct `std::iter::Take<std::iter::Repeat<Option<_>>>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether `x` should be an `Iterator` or a `Vec`.

## Iterator

```rust
let x = i.into_iter().flatten().chain(iter::repeat(None)).take(3);
```

Here's every step explained:

1. `into_iter()` creates an iterator from our `Option`. Our `next()` call would return the whole `Vec`.
2. `flatten` iterates the `Vec` and thus all its elements
3. `chain(iter::repeat(None))` adds unlimited `None`s to the iteration
4. `take(3)` limits the total amount of elements to three.

However, this assumes that you want to have exactly three elements always and either limit the `Vec` or fill it up with `None`s.

## Vec

Since `take(3)` returns an iterator, but `unwrap_or` returns a `Vec` on an existing vector, we need to transform the iterator into a `Vec` via `collect()`:

```rust
let x = i.unwrap_or(iter::repeat(None).take(3).collect());
```

Now the types match.